# Displaying top 10 most occuring words in a file in descending order

Tags: java

i am trying to make the code more  neat and efficient. iam trying to implement zamzela's[u will find one of the answers down]  method. iam having trouble implementing the comparator

public class WordCountExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Set<WordCount> wordcount = new HashSet<WordCount>();

    File file = new File("c:\\test\\input1.txt");    //path to the file

    String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);   // converts a file into a string


    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");     // split the line on whitespace,
                                            // would return an array of words

    for (String s : words) {

        wordcount.add(new WordCount(s));

        WordCount.incCount();

    }

         /*here WordCount is the name of comparator class*/

          Collections.sort(wordcount,new WordCount());   //getting a error here 


    for (WordCount w : wordcount) {

        System.out.println(w.getValue() + " " + w.getCount());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You forgot the question. (Hint: "do this for me" isn't a question.)

Comment: Is it homework? And what is the question?

Comment: If you just wish for people to review your code, try posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Congratulations on having that program :) - (serious mode) What is your question?

Comment: Calm down guys. He actually has a question (without question mark though): "how to you display only top 10 of them in descending order".

Comment: is performance an issue? there is O(n) solution, but it is pretty messy,the O(nlogn) solution is much neater.

Comment: for guys who did not understand the question:the program is displaying all the words in a file according to their occurances i want only top 10 words

Answer (score 3):

Don't store just the word count as the value in your map. Store an object containing the word and its number of occurrences.

```
public class `WordWithOccurrences` {
    private final String word;
    private int occurrences;
    // ...
}
```

And your map should thus be a `Map<String, WordWithOccurrences>`.

Then sort the list of values based on their occurrences property, and iterate through the last 10 values to display their word property (or sort in reverse order and display the first ten values).

You'll have to use a custom comparator to sort your `WordWithOccurrences` instances.

Comment: note that though this is the most elegant way, there is O(n) solution, while this solution is O(nlogn). nevertheless, +1.

Comment: when ever i iterate it is giving all the words.how to iterate and display only 10 values?

Comment: Initialize a counter to 0, increment the counter at each iteration, and break out of the loop when the counter reaches 10.

Comment: we can do that in arrays but how do u do that in arraylist?

Comment: int i = 0; for (WordWithOccurrences w : list) {System.out.println(w.getWord() + ":" + w.getOccurrences());i++; if (i == 10) {break;}}

Answer (score 2):

I think best aproach is to make a class Word

```
    public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
    private String value;
    private Integer count;

    public Word(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        count = 1;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void incCount() {
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Word)
            return value.equals(((Word) obj).getValue());
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        return count.compareTo(o.getCount());
    }
}
```

you can work with HashSet becase count will be kept in the bean and after you populate everything you can do the sort Collections.sort(array); and take first 10 elements.

Comment: I am trying to solve the program using ur method i am having trouble implementing the comparator in the code.This is what i have

Answer (score 1):

finally solved the program. here is a perfectly working program which reads a file, counts the number of words and list the top 10 most occuring words in descending order

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Occurance {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {         
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> wordcount =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    try { 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                  new FileReader("c:\\test\\input1.txt"));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            str = str.toLowerCase(); // convert to lower case 
            String[] words = str.split("\\s+"); //split the line on whitespace, would return an array of words

            for( String word : words ) {
              if( word.length() == 0 ) {
                continue; 
              }

              Integer occurences = wordcount.get(word);

              if( occurences == null) {
                occurences = 1;
              } else {
                occurences++;
              }

              wordcount.put(word, occurences);
            }

                } 

        } 
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }




    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.addAll(wordcount.values());

    Collections.sort(values, Collections.reverseOrder());

    int last_i = -1;


    for (Integer i : values.subList(0, 9)) { 
        if (last_i == i) // without duplicates
            continue;
        last_i = i;




            for (String s : wordcount.keySet()) { 

            if (wordcount.get(s) == i) // which have this value  
               System.out.println(s+ " " + i);


    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your program doesn't actually work, here's a hint:

You're comparing on a per character basis yourself, and without going through that code I bet is is wrong:

```
int idx1 = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
  if ((!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) || (i + 1 == str.length())) { 
    if (i - idx1 > 1) { 
       if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) 
         i++;
       String word = str.substring(idx1 + 1, i);
       if (wordcount.containsKey(word)) { 
          wordcount.put(word, wordcount.get(word) + 1);
       } else { 
          wordcount.put(word, 1);
       } 
     }          
     idx1 = i;
   } 
 }
```

Try to use Java's built in functionality:

```
  String[] words = str.split("\\s+"); //split the line on whitespace, would return an array of words

  for( String word : words ) {
    if( word.length() == 0 ) {
      continue; //for empty lines, split would return at least one element which is ""; so account for that
    }

    Integer occurences = wordcount.get(word);

    if( occurences == null) {
      occurences = 1;
    } else {
      occurences++;
    }

    wordcount.put(word, occurences);
  }
```

Comment: applied ur method and edited my program to use java built in methods still having trouble getting only ten elements

Comment: @javastudent Well, after getting the words and counts you'd have to sort the result (follow JB's suggestion) and get the first 10 elements. Hint: `List#subList(...)` or use iterators and stop after the 10th element.

Comment: tried that but if i apply sublist method or iterators the program is going in a long loop with sublists of various sizes. if poss pls modify my prog and post it

Comment: @javastudent It's your assignment, so you should do the work. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask for help in understanding, but please don't expect us to write code for you. You won't learn anything from that. If sublists don't work for you, please show off your modified code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [`java.util.Comparator`](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.util.Comparator).  You can define your own comparator which you can pass to `Collections.sort()`.  In your case, you would sort the *keys* of your `wordcount` by their count.  Finally, just take the first ten items of the sorted collection.

If your `wordcount` map has too many items, though, you might need something more efficient.  It is possible to do this in linear time, by keeping an ordered array of size 10 into which you insert each key, always dropping the key with the lowest count.